# Unable to get JSON data from Img2Json API for large files in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, amazon-s3

I am using http://img2json.appspot.com/ to retrieve and store the Exif data for user uploaded images. I noticed that for smaller files things work great. For larger files, or for files with a large amount of Exif data, the file is stored but the Exif data is not. I don't know if this is because the service is taking to long to produce the JSON, or if there is a memory issue since I'm storing all the JSON in a PHP array.

My code for retrieving the Exif data for a user uploaded image is as follows:

```
$exifd = file_get_contents("http://img2json.appspot.com/go/url=http://myURL.com/$fileName");
$response = json_decode($exifd, true);


$shut = $response['exif']['ShutterSpeedValue'];
$iso = $response['exif']['ISOSpeedRatings'];
$dateTime = $response['exif']['DateTime'];
$aperture = $response['exif']['ApertureValue'];
$focalLength = $response['exif']['FocalLength'];
$make = $response['exif']['Make'];
$model = $response['exif']['Model'];
$software = $response['exif']['Software'];
$flash = $response['exif']['Flash'];

$sql="INSERT INTO EXIF (uniqueID, dateTime, aperture, focalLength, make, model, software, shutterSpeed, ISO, flash)
VALUES('$id', '$dateTime', '$aperture', '$focalLength', '$make', '$model', '$software', '$shut', '$iso', '$flash')";  

if (!mysql_query($sql,$link))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

}else{  
echo "Something went wrong while uploading your file... sorry.";  
}
```

As I mentioned before, this works great for the most part, but it doesn't work on large files (large in size or large in the amount of Exif data) and here and there a small file will fail as well.

Here is an image that works fine for me: http://img2json.appspot.com/go/?callback=hello&url=http://cloudousmain.s3.amazonaws.com/olympus-c960.jpg

Two that fail: http://img2json.appspot.com/go/?callback=hello&url=http://cloudousmain.s3.amazonaws.com/54img.JPG

and

http://img2json.appspot.com/go/?callback=hello&url=http://cloudousmain.s3.amazonaws.com/IMG_20130329_120227.jpg

I've increased the memory in the ini file with no success. Also, it might be worth noting that while images are being processed a progress bar is displayed until things are finished (or supposed to be finished). Any ideas?

Edit: switching to curl and using var_dump reveals that the images that "don't work" are dumping as NULL, while the ones that work fine give me an array of Exif data as expected.

Comment: I quickly went through this in an attempt to reproduce the issue and I have two guesses as to what went wrong. First, no exceptions were thrown, no warnings and no notices so I think a fair assumption is malformed json.

My second guess in the matter is that there is an issue with how php handles the response coming back. I don't know if it is trying to encode some of the odd groupings "x00"

Comment: I suspect the JSON is the issue as well, although I'm not sure why. Also, none of the particular values I need get the odd "x00" looking things, so I'm wondering if that would matter. Since the JSON is decoded in PHP and I get back an Array, can't I just skip the "messed up" values?

Comment: The failure is happening during the json_decode function. So something is causing this to fail. You are handling string values when storing the result of file_get_contents. Which is most likely where a either character encoding is required. It doesn't matter that you aren't accessing the values of what may be the culprit. I would try to use curl over file_get_contents if I were you and dumping it to file. That may help your debugging issue.

Comment: I did as you suggested and came to the conclusion that the JSON is invalid. The images that "work" give me a dump I expect. The ones that don't give me one big fat NULL. When I put the non-working JSON through JSONLint.com I get parse error on `"Tag0xa420": "OAEL01\x00\x00\x00\/` because its `Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['`. I think I'll try removing the junk before decoding the JSON, if possible, or maybe decoding line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up defaulting to PHP's Exif functions when the JSON was NULL. Not what I wanted to do, but it worked.

Comment: You should send the service owner an email notifying them of the corrupt json.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's an AWS error, which is written in XML and cannot be parsed for EXIF data. I'm getting "Access Denied" when I try to view the bad images in the browser, but the good one shows the image.

- **Fail**: http://cloudousmain.s3.amazonaws.com/54img.JPG

  ```
  <Error>
      <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
      <Message>Access Denied</Message>
      <RequestId>2537951DEE216FEB</RequestId>
      <HostId>Ep4//A7Oq+n/C3ilB5jyazx0Bs9fQfMRyNg+pX/rs+dkziFhJIkgHNWHc+CAZVgR</HostId>
  </Error>
  ```
- **Pass**: http://cloudousmain.s3.amazonaws.com/olympus-c960.jpg

To check for this in the code, ping the header for the image file and check if the content type is `application/xml` or if the http code is 403. I'd suggest either using `http_head()` or  flagging `CURLOPT_HEADER` in `curl_setopt()` for this information.

Comment: I deleted many of the images and reuploaded new ones, which may explain the access denied.